# Efficient SQL query to find gap in consecutive numeric data (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, gaps-and-islands, myisam

I have a table with column "time" (INT unsigned), every row represents one second and I need to find gaps in time (missing seconds).
I have tried with this query (to find the first time before a gap):

```
SELECT t1.time
FROM `table` AS t1
LEFT JOIN `table` AS t2 ON t2.time=(t1.time+1)
WHERE t2.time IS NULL
ORDER BY TIME ASC
LIMIT 1
```

And it works but it's too slow for big tables (near 100M rows)
Is there some faster solution?

EXPLAIN query:
[image]

SHOW CREATE:

```
CREATE TABLE `candles` (
  `time` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `open` float unsigned NOT NULL,
  `high` float unsigned NOT NULL,
  `low` float unsigned NOT NULL,
  `close` float unsigned NOT NULL,
  `vb` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `vs` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `trades` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`time`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: what does `select version();` show?

Comment: 5.7.24 is something in MySQL 8 that could help to improve this query?

Comment: yes, mysql 8 or mariadb 10.2+ make this so much easier

Comment: can you post the solution for MySQL 8? could be useful anyway (and also for future references to this question)

Comment: can you show output for `show create table yourtablename;` and `explain SELECT...rest of your query`?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query and What should the result look like?

Comment: @ysfh I have added that info

Answer (score 1):

If DB version is `8.0`, then *The Recursive Common Table Expression* might be used such as

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS 
(
  SELECT 1 AS n
  UNION ALL
  SELECT n + 1 AS value
    FROM cte
   WHERE cte.n < (SELECT MAX(time) FROM tab )
)
SELECT n AS gaps
  FROM cte
  LEFT JOIN tab
    ON n=time
 WHERE cte.n > (SELECT MIN(time) FROM tab ) 
   AND time IS NULL
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5456c3cedb26f89e3a95aef83e4cc13a)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL 5.7, this is a use case where user variables might be helpful:

```
select max(time)
from (
    select t.time, @rn := @rn + 1 as rn 
    from (select time from mytable order by time) t
    cross join (select @rn := 0) r
) t
group by time - rn
```

This addresses the question as a gaps-and-islands problem. The idea is to identify groups of records where time increments without gaps (the islands). For this, we assign an incrementing id to each row, ordered by time; whenever the difference between `time` and the auto-increment changes, you know there is a gap.

Comment: I've tried that query and it's 20X times slower. Maybe because it gets all the gaps, but I'm ok just finding the first time before the gap (to find end time of that gap it's a really fast query then)

Answer (score 0):

With mysql 8, you can use LEAD():

```
select time from (
    select time, lead(time, 1) over (order by time) next_time
    from `table`
) t
where time+1 != next_time
```

In earlier versions, I might do something like:

```
select prev_time as time from (
    select @prev_time+0 as prev_time,if(@prev_time:=time,time,time) as time
    from (select @prev_time:=null) initvars
    cross join (select time from `table` order by time) t
) t
where time != prev_time+1
```

Either will not include the greatest time, where your original query would have.

I think the group by required to treat it as a strict gaps and islands problem would be too expensive with that many records.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=4ca87481961b1dbf7de423b5996e9883)

Comment: I didn't tried the MySQL 8 version, but the earlier version is much slower than my query. Maybe my query is OK is just that slow for the amount of data and there isn't any faster way to do that?

Comment: the table you show is one with 100M records?  I'm having trouble believing you would have data for that many distinct times.

Comment: the other thing you might try is making it `... from candles use index () left join ...`; occasionally that will help.